# Modal Closes right after it opens c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I wanted to use a modal (by clicking on a button) to insert data to a table (with calling action in another controller)
Here is my cshtml code:

```
    <section class="basic-elements">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="px-3">
                        <form class="form">
                            <div class="form-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-6 col-md-12 mb-1">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            <label for="roundText">Clinic Name</label>
                                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.clinics, new SelectList(Model.clinics, "Id", "Name"), new { @class = "form-control round" })
                                        </fieldset>
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-round dropdown-toggle mr-1" id="btnAddClinic" onclick="ShowModalAddClinic()">add new clinic</button>
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <button class="btn btn-success btn-round dropdown-toggle mr-1" id="btnAddClinic" data-toggle="dropdown">insert</button>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and it's my modal code:

```
@section Scripts
{
    <link href="~/SweetAlert2/sweetalert2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/SweetAlert2/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    function ShowModalAddClinic()
     {
            $('#AddClinic').modal('show');
        }

    </script>
}

@section Modals
{
    <div class="modal fade" id="AddClinic" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">ایجاد کلینیک</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 mb-1">
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <label for="basicInput">Clinic Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control round" id="ClinicName">
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <a class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">close</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="AddNewClinic()">add</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

But when I click on "add new clinic" , modal shows and immediately disappeared.
I would be so appreciated id you can help me about this problem.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I Found My Answer :
The Reason was using "Form Tag".
I Removed "Form Tag" and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `<button>` element is with `type="submit"` attribute. Thus, when you click the button, it submits the form and reloads the page.

You need to add the `type="button"` attribute so it will not submit the form and reload the page.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-round dropdown-toggle mr-1" 
    id="btnAddClinic" onclick="ShowModalAddClinic()">add new clinic</button>
```

Besides, from the [Bootstrap Modal documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/), you can use the `data-toggle="modal"` and `data-target="#AddClinic"` attributes to open the modal without the Bootstrap modal function.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-round dropdown-toggle mr-1" 
    id="btnAddClinic" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddClinic">add new clinic</button>
```

Comment: [MVC Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ivnlHg)